# Is any 1-form conformally closed in 2 dimensions?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, conformal-geometry, linear-pde

On $\mathbb{R}^2$, say, given an arbitrary 1-form $u = u_x dx + u_y dy$, does there exist a (non-zero) function $f(x,y)$ such that $f u$ is an closed 1-form, i.e.
$$
\partial_x(f u_y) = \partial_y (f u_x) \ \ ?
$$

This is a 1st order linear PDE for $f$. I guess given the appropriate smoothness conditions, such an equation always has solutions. Can they be explicitly constructed in terms of $u$?

[Local existence/construction of $f$ is enough.]

Comment: Maybe I should explain where this comes from:
I was trying to understand if all 1st order ODEs can be made 'exact'.

Starting from an equation of the form $y'(x) + H(x,y)=0$, one wants to find an `integrating factor' $f(x,y)$ such that $f y' + f H= \frac{dg}{dx} = \partial_y g y' + \partial_x g$ for some function $g(x,y)$. Then the equation can be solved by integrating.
This can be done if $f(H,1) = (\partial_x g, \partial_y g)$, i.e. if the 1-form $H dx + dy$ is conformally exact. Locally this is equivalent to being conformally closed.

Comment: It would be helpful to know under what conditions the function $f$ can be found explicitly. For example in the case when $f$ is separable, $f=a(x)b(y)$, I expect that $a$, $b$ can be found explicitly in terms of $H$. So maybe a good supplementary question is: For which choices of $H$ can the 1-form $u= H dx +dy$ be made closed by multiplying by the special type of function $f=a(x)b(y)$ ?

Comment: A counterexample is the one-form $xdy$. If $f(x,y)xdy$ is closed, then it is exact i.e. $$f(x,y)xdy=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy.$$ This forces that $g=g(y)$ and $f(x,y)x=g(y)$. Then necessarily, $f$ is of the form $K/x$ for a constant $K$. So there are no smooth solutions for $f$ around points where $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
I would not class this as a counterexample because I am happy with local existence of $f$ in the neighbourhood of some point -- in other words I don't mind if f blows up and/or vanishes in some places.

Comment: @Natha: But you can't do it in a neighborhood of a point on the line $x=0$. Here's the main point, although I don't know a super-easy proof. If $\omega(p)\ne 0$, then I get a family of curves in a neighborhood of $p$ given by $\omega=0$, and I can choose coordinates $(u,v)$ on perhaps a slightly smaller neighborhood so that those curves are level curves of $u$. That means that $\omega = f\,du$, so $\frac1f\omega = du$ is exact.

Comment: I mean local existence of $f$ at $\textit{some}$ point -- I don't mind which point! Certainly it's enough if $f$ exists 'almost everywhere', where I will remain a bit undecided about what I mean by that